# micro-frontend developement using webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, bundling-and-minification

I am trying to build micro-frontend eco system.
There are many team developing different component to make app work together in single page as single page app. All the component should be builded and deployed independently and should referenced in single HTML page to start working together by resolving at run-time.
For example, In production we should be having following script file in html page:

```
<script src="http://deploy-server/external/vendor1.js" />
<script src="http://deploy-server/external/vendor2.js" />
<script src="http://deploy-server/external/vendor3.js" />
<script src="http://deploy-server/internal/comp1.js" />
<script src="http://deploy-server/internal/comp2.js" />
<script src="http://deploy-server/internal/comp3.js" />
```

Now, below would be package details:

```
vendor1 -> Reactjs, react-dom, react-router (most used lib for making react eco-system, Used by all internal component scripts)
vendor2.js -> react-datepicker, lodash, (libraires used by comp2.js)
vendor3.js -> Used by comp3.js
```

comp1.js,comp2.js,comp3.js -> Using vendor1.js and may be using or may start using vendor2 and vendor3 js modules in future.

How to bundle external vendor files and internal libraries separately and at the same time want to use them to be shared across different team for development. Suppose i have bundled vendor1.js, how it should be used for developing and building comp3, comp4,.... ?

I tried building vendor1.js using "shared" but when referring it with comp2.js, getting runtime error.

Edit: Adding code i tried
To share vendor file different team, i created vendor file in app1, having below webpack.config.js

```
   entry: {
      home: { 
        import: './src/app1-index.js',
        dependOn: 'shared',
        filename: 'js/app1.js',
      },
      shared: ['react', 'react-dom', 'react-is']
    },
    output: {
      publicPath: '/',
      path: path.join(__dirname, '/build/'),
      filename: `js/vendor.js`,
    },
```

This has created 2 files:

> ```
>        Asset      Size
>   js/app1.js  4.82 KiB  [emitted]  [name: home]
> js/vendor.js   993 KiB  [emitted]  [name: shared]
> ```

Using this 2 files together is working fine because i have bundled them in single bundle process. Below is the html I used:

```
  <script src="/build/js/vendor.js" ></script>
  <script src="/build/js/app1.js" ></script>
```

Now, since i want vendor file to be shared across different team, in another app, app2, i kept below webpack.config:

```
entry: './src/app2-index.js',
externals : {
  react: 'react',
  'react-dom': 'react-dom',
  'react-is': 'react-is'
},
output: {
  publicPath: '/',
  path: path.join(__dirname, '/build/'),
  filename: `js/app2.js`,
},
```

This created only 1 file:

> ```
>      Asset     Size
> js/app2.js  6.3 KiB  [emitted]  [name: main]
> ```

Mentioned externals as modules which would be served by vendor.js created earlier.

Now on using app2.js with vendor file created earlier is not working. I copied vendor.js from previous build folder to app2 build folder:

```
  <script src="/build/js/vendor.js" ></script>
  <script src="/build/js/app2.js" ></script>
```

This is throwing error:

> ReferenceError: react is not defined

I understand why it is not working may be because they are not bundled in single bundle process. But then how can we achieve this using webpack?

I want to bundle external libraries in vendor.js and want to distribute to different team to start using it, but they(diff team) should not be bundle those vendor modules while returning their app bundle. Dependent modules would be resolved only at runtime in browser.

Similarly once comp1 is developed, team1, will share their file with team2 to build comp2 assuming comp2 is dependent on comp1, but the sharing should not be done through npm package rather it should be through script file and team2 can assume it will be resolve by their webpack module comp2, at run-time.

Can we achieve this in webpack? I tried using external and shared. Any other options should i try?

Comment: Basically, want vendor file to be created separately and it should be used in development and direct hosting as script tag to be used by other libraries. 
Planning to use same bundle for development and hosting because to make sure same version of packaged modules are used.

Comment: Add examples of your code and Webpack configuration. Also, "getting runtime error" is supremely useless.

Comment: read this post https://medium.com/@lucamezzalira/micro-frontends-decisions-framework-ebcd22256513

Comment: and check this lib, https://single-spa.js.org/ it will solve most of your conserns.

Comment: @felixmosh Thanks for reply. The single-spa.js is good option but want to know if we can achieve this using bundling. I dont want to create app the way single-spa suggest. I want one team micro-frontend can be used by another as composition component.

Comment: @AKX Thanks for reply. I didn't putted code as it was very simple and moreover I need help in thinking building approach, rather than any correction on code i wrote. I think there must be some other options that i must try. Anyways i have added the code i tried also. Thanks once again.